# Determining O-runtime of simple loop

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I have this simple loop in pseudocode:

```
i = 2

while i < n do
    i = i * i
```

How would I determine the Big-O for this algorithm with respect to `n`?

In this case `i` would go: `2`, `4`, `16`, `256`, `65536`, etc, each time `i` itself is squared. I'm not sure how to come up with an expression to describe this.

Answer (score 3):

In first sight the time complexity is `O(log(n))` as `n` in condition of `while` is static. However, you can find tight bound if scrutinize more. To do this as you follow the steps they are `2^(2^k)`. For example for `k = 0, 1, 2, ...` you can see `i` is growth `2, 4, 16, 246, ...`. Hence, The exact complexity is `O(log(log(n)))`.